# boost qi::grammar not updating valuetype using spirit/phoenix

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following problem:

upon parsing a text using qi::grammar the struct grammer is not returning the values of the parsed object.

The Grammer

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct PositionalDegreeImpl_grammer : qi::grammar<Iterator,PositionalDegreeImpl>
{

    struct Type_ : qi::symbols<char,horus::parsergenerator::nmea::CardinalDirection::Direction>
    {
        Type_()
        {
            this->add("E", horus::parsergenerator::nmea::CardinalDirection::Direction::EAST)
                    ("N",  horus::parsergenerator::nmea::CardinalDirection::Direction::NORTH)
                    ("W",  horus::parsergenerator::nmea::CardinalDirection::Direction::WEST)
                    ("S",  horus::parsergenerator::nmea::CardinalDirection::Direction::SOUTH);
        }
    } type_;

    qi::rule<Iterator,PositionalDegreeImpl> r;
    PositionalDegreeImpl_grammer() : PositionalDegreeImpl_grammer::base_type(r)
    {
        r = (double_ >> ',' >> type_)

                [
                   qi::_val = boost::phoenix::construct<PositionalDegreeImpl>(qi::_2,qi::_1)
                ];
    }

};
```

During the debug session is can see that the correct Constructor is being called, with the correct values.

```
std::string str = "123.2,W";  
PositionalDegreeImpl val(horus::parsergenerator::nmea::CardinalDirection::Direction::EAST,1.0);


PositionalDegreeImpl_grammer<std::string::iterator> pos_deg_parser;
bool r = qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), pos_deg_parser, &val);

if (!r || val.degrees() != 123.2)
{
    std::cout<< "Err" <<std::endl;
}
```

val contains the initial values after parsing. I have the feeling i am over looking something.

Pure virutal base

```
class PositionalDegree
{
public:
    /*! number of degrees of the position */
    virtual double degrees() const = 0;

    /*! the direction {N,S,E,W} of the position */
    virtual const CardinalDirection& direction() const = 0;

    /*! Provide the assignment operator */
    virtual PositionalDegree& operator=(const PositionalDegree&) = 0;
};
```

Implementation

```
class PositionalDegreeImpl : public PositionalDegree
{
private:
    double _degrees;
    CardinalDirectionImpl _direction;
public:
    PositionalDegreeImpl();
    explicit PositionalDegreeImpl(PositionalDegree const &other);
    PositionalDegreeImpl(PositionalDegreeImpl const &other);
    PositionalDegreeImpl(CardinalDirectionImpl const & cardinal, double degrees);


    virtual ~PositionalDegreeImpl();

    virtual double degrees() const;

    virtual const CardinalDirection& direction() const;

    virtual PositionalDegree& operator=(const PositionalDegree& other);
    PositionalDegreeImpl& operator=(const PositionalDegreeImpl& other);

};
```

Any ideas, tips would be appreciated.

Regards Auke

Comment: Hi Auke. Welcome to SO. If you're sharing _that_ much code, you should really have made this a SSCCE. People are exceptionally bad at mentally compiling C++ code, especially scattered across multiple, out-of-sequence, snippets. Add to that that there are very few Spirit whizzes here...

Comment: In fact I didn't. I got frustrated getting the code into workable shape. And then - suddenly - while doing the routine code formatting stuff my eye caught this bit of trivia, which  happens to be a Spirit pitfall. If it had been something more pedestrian, I would not have been able to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing parentheses here:

```
qi::rule<Iterator,PositionalDegreeImpl()> r;
```

If I remember correctly, the absolute requirement to include the parens will be lifted in an upcoming version (might already be there in 1_57_0

Here's a self contained example

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f79534496d608fdf)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace horus { namespace parsergenerator { namespace nmea {

    struct CardinalDirection {
        enum class Direction { EAST, NORTH, WEST, SOUTH };
    };

    struct PositionalDegreeImpl {
        PositionalDegreeImpl(CardinalDirection::Direction direction, double d)
         : _dir(direction), _degrees(d)
        {
        }

        double degrees() const { return _degrees; }

      private:
        CardinalDirection::Direction _dir;
        double _degrees;
    };

    template<typename Iterator, typename T = PositionalDegreeImpl>
    struct PositionalDegreeGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator,T()>
    {
        PositionalDegreeGrammar() : PositionalDegreeGrammar::base_type(r)
        {
            r = (qi::double_ >> ',' >> type_)
                [
                    qi::_val = boost::phoenix::construct<T>(qi::_2,qi::_1)
                ];
        }
      private:
        struct Type_ : qi::symbols<char, CardinalDirection::Direction> {
            Type_() {
                this->add
                    ("E", CardinalDirection::Direction::EAST)
                    ("N",  CardinalDirection::Direction::NORTH)
                    ("W",  CardinalDirection::Direction::WEST)
                    ("S",  CardinalDirection::Direction::SOUTH);
            }
        } type_;

        qi::rule<Iterator,T()> r;
    };

} } }

int main() 
{
    using namespace horus::parsergenerator::nmea;
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    PositionalDegreeImpl val(CardinalDirection::Direction::EAST, 1.0);

    PositionalDegreeGrammar<It> pos_deg_parser;

    std::string const str = "123.2,W";  
    It f = str.begin(), l = str.end();

    bool r = qi::parse(f, l, pos_deg_parser, val);

    if (r)
        std::cout << val.degrees() << ": " << std::boolalpha << (123.2==val.degrees()) << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "parsing failed\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
123.2: true
```

Comment: Thank you sehe changin the template to `qi::grammar<Iterator,PositionalDegreeImpl()>` and your suggestion made it work.

Comment: Added a SSCCE. Caveat: the float comparision [might not do what you expect](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith).